# Why proprietary template engines are used instead of html5?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, web-frontend

All the popular frontend frameworks(angular, ember, react etc) use proprietary template engines. I'm wondering why a proprietary template syntax is used instead the standard html5 `<template/>` tag. Is there a technical reason?

Comment: Probably for compatibility.  Not everything (and by that I mean not IE) supports the `<template/>` tag: http://caniuse.com/#search=template

Comment: @Hazmat old IE is now Edge so it does.

Comment: According to http://status.modern.ie/templateelement only the *preview* release (not the current version) of Edge supports `<template>`.

Comment: Still I believe a polyfill could be implemented for older browsers, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

They're different beasts: template engines do a lot more than hold HTML for filling in later.

They include loop control, conditionals, various ways of implementing EL engines, and so on.

That's out of the scope of the  tag to my understanding (which is limited and possibly wrong).

In addition, template engine designers have a lot of different... *ahem*... views regarding what should or should not be the responsibility/functionality of a template, which is one reason there are eighteen million of them.